# Reverse a string for only the alphabets in a sentence not numbers or special characters in java

Tags: java, string, java-8

I want to implement a method to return a string after reversing only the alphabets `[a-zA-Z]` in a sentence, not number or special characters. Reversing has to be done word-by-word. eg: for `25000rs for 1 LCD` it should be `25000sr rof 1 DCL`.

```
public class Main {
    static String reverseWords(String inputString) { 
    String[] words = inputString.split(" ");

    String reverseString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
    {
        String word = words[i];

        String reverseWord = "";

        for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
        }

        reverseString = reverseString + reverseWord + " ";
    }
    return reverseString;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str1 = "1 cup of hot coffee costs 8.00, whereas cold coffee costs 45.00."; 
    System.out.println(reverseWords(str1));  

    String str2 = "It Costs 25000rs for 1 LCD Projector."; 
    System.out.println(reverseWords(str2)); 

    String str3 = "8990.33"; 
    System.out.println(reverseWords(str3)); 
}
}
```

### This is the output I want:

> 1 puc fo toh eeffoc stsoc 8.00, saerehw dloc eeffoc stsoc 45.00.
>
> tI stsoC 25000sr rof 1 DCL rotcejorP.
>
> 8990.33

### This is the output I am getting:

> 1 puc fo toh eeffoc stsoc ,00.8 saerehw dloc eeffoc stsoc .00.54
>
> tI stsoC sr00052 rof 1 DCL .rotcejorP
>
> 33.0998

Comment: Whats your issue?

Comment: I am getting this as a output- "1 puc fo toh eeffoc stsoc ,00.8 saerehw dloc eeffoc stsoc .00.54" instead of "1 puc fo toh eeffoc stsoc 8.00, saerehw dloc eeffoc stsoc 45.00."

Comment: Pl. post it on your question to get help from others. Whats output you are getting and whats you are expecting.

Comment: This is not the output you’re getting with this code. This code swallows non-word characters completely, so they do not appear in the output. Besides that, expressions like `new String(reverseString)` make no sense, as `reverseString` is already a `String`.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I posted the updated code. I was trying to resolve the issue and didn't realize while posting that I had made changes in the original code.

Comment: I assume this is homework? Any limitations on what you can/can't use?

Comment: There are no limitations as such on what we can use or cannot.

Answer (score 2):

You are just splitting at space characters, which makes every sequence of non-space characters a “word”.

This task is a canonical use case for the regex [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/regex/Matcher.html)’s `appendReplacement`/`appendTail` loop, which you can always use when the intended replacement logic is too complex for a simple [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) on a `String`:

```
static final Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("\\pL+"); // class "L" means "letter"

static String reverseWords(String inputString) { 
    Matcher m = WORD.matcher(inputString);
    if(!m.find()) return inputString;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(inputString.length());
    do {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, new StringBuilder(m.group()).reverse().toString());
    } while(m.find());
    return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

(Starting with Java 9, this API also supports using `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

---

But in this specific case, the operation can also be done slightly more efficient:

```
static String reverseWords(String inputString) { 
    Matcher m = WORD.matcher(inputString);
    if(!m.find()) return inputString;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);
    do {
        for(int ix1 = m.start(), ix2 = m.end() - 1; ix1 < ix2; ix1++, ix2--) {
            sb.setCharAt(ix1, inputString.charAt(ix2));
            sb.setCharAt(ix2, inputString.charAt(ix1));
        }
    } while(m.find());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Main {
    static String reverse(String inputString) { 
    String[] words = inputString.split(" ");
    boolean set = false; 
    String reverseString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
    {
        String word = words[i];

        String reverseWord = "";

        for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {  
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(word.charAt(j))){
                
            reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
            set = false; 
        }else{
            set = true ; 
            break ; 
        }
        }
        if(set == true){
            reverseString = reverseString + reverseWord + word +  " "; 
        }
        
        reverseString = reverseString + reverseWord +  " ";
      
    }
    return reverseString;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String st1 = "1 cup of hot coffee costs 8.00, whereas cold coffee costs 45.00.";
    System.out.println(Main.reverse(st1));  

    String st2 = "It Costs 25000rs for 1 LCD Projector."; 
    System.out.println(Main.reverse(st2)); 

    String st3 = "8990.33"; 
    System.out.println(Main.reverse(st3)); 
    
    String st4 = "Hello Everyone Today we are going to learn 1-10 table."; 
    System.out.println(Main.reverse(st4)); 
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome @hack_harsh you are answering an old and unquoted question and your answer seems not to add something to the topic. Please consider to expand your answer with some more explaination and context or to remove it, thank you